# Reporting Service Keeps Asking for Credential

Tags: reporting-services

I just deployed a reporting service page at our server. But every time I access the page, it keeps asking me for username and password to the datasource (our database). 
[image]
Since the report will be opened for public users, I have to keep the username and password confidential and couldn't share it with the public user.
I know there's a way to hide this. I'm thinking there's thing that I missed when configuring the setting for the deployment. Could you guys help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the properties of the datasource of the report and look at the credentials piece.  There are several options there - from there you can set up credentials for the report to run as and your users will not see this.  That should do it.