# Reporting services always requires credentials

Tags: reporting-services

I'm building SSRS reports with the goal of downloading them as XML through URL. That is,

`example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%2fReportName&parameterInput=parameterValue&rs:Format=XML`

For the purposes of building tools and not having to authenticate for the time being, we'd like to disable credentials checking. However, no matter the settings specified, I'm prompted for credentials in a popup dialog.

To test that my "connect using" settings weren't being overlooked, in the reports manager I selected "Connect using credentials supplied by the user running the report". When this is selected, I'm still prompted once for credentials in a dialog, then a second time [as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695413/reporting-service-keeps-asking-for-credential).

I've tried adding an unattended execution account, not requiring credentials, and supplying credentials stored in the report. None of these have worked and I'm wondering whether there's a setting I've missed in the rsreportserver.config, or something beyond my control?

Comment: I think this has to do with using the url your report manager is asking you to connect using your credentials not the actual report.

Comment: Go to the site settings on the report manager and check your account there.

Comment: @newGuy would you mind clarifying what to check? I assume you mean to check users under the Security section, but what should I be checking for? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared Data Source in your reporting services (which will hold database connection credentials) and use it in your report. After that you don't need to pass Data Source credentials via URL when you are generating a report.

[image: Shared Data Source in SSRS]